# Python Long/Lat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I am new to python and I am doing an apprenticeship at work, I have the following code but it is not adding the longitude and latitude to my data frame, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
sales = pd.read_csv('file_path/ppd_data.csv')

sales['co-ordinates'] = sales['postcode'].apply(geolocator.geocode).apply(lambda x: (x.latitude, x.longitude))
sales

sales.head()
```

Hoping to get the longitude and latitude into the main data frame.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43JZY.png) This data is from the land registry and I want to add the longitude and latitude for creating the mapping points.

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: We need to know what `geolocator` is, and what your data looks like. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.